# Triggering baseline indexing without dyn admin

Tags: atg, endeca, atg-dynamo

We are working on ATG/Endeca integration 11.2 but don't have the dyn admin console in production so we can't schedule the jobs from the console. How can this be accomplished without the console? I have read the documentation but not able to understand clearly how to do it.

Comment: Is this the documentation which you read? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E55783_02/Platform.11-2/ATGEndecaIntegrationGuide/html/s0411atgcontentadministrationcomponen01.html

Comment: Yes but I am more of a Endeca person that ATG so was having trouble figuring it out. I will try to get the ATG team to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a REST to call the indexBaseline of the ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin component.

Try:

```
curl http://localhost:8001/rest/bean/atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin/indexBaseline
```

replace localhost:8001 by the address:port of your dyn admin.

I worked on a project where they had a script that called this, using a curl.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the indexing using the /atg/commerce/endeca/index/ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin.baselineSchedule option.

For triggering from outside, you can write a custom RMI component in the ATG/Endeca integration server and that RMI component can trigger the indexing within the server. Now, from an external server, you can invoke this RMI. Using this approach you can check the job status and also get the progress if needed.